# Does Python3 still need raw string in regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

In Python 2, when dealing with regular expression we use r'expression', do we still need prepend "r" in Python 3, since I know Python 3 use Unicode by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Backslash escape sequences are still present in Python 3 strings, thus raw strings prefixed with `r` make a difference as shown in this simple example:

```
>>> s = 'hello\n'
>>> raw = r'hello\n'
>>> s
hello\n
>>> raw
hello\\n
>>> print(s)
hello

>>> print(raw)
hello\n
```

Answer (score 1):

Raw strings are still useful for writing characters like \ without escaping them. This is generally useful in regex and window paths etc.